# Grouping of directories in a more functional way

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

Can someone give me insights on how to convert this Scala code (Java imperative way) to a more functional way?

It is grouping of directories by say total of 4GB subdividing the directories/files into 4 groups with 1GB limit for each group, adding the each group to a list.

```
object MyMapper {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var map: Map[String, Long] = Map[String, Long]();
    map += ("a" -> 5);
    map += ("b" -> 5);
    map += ("c" -> 3);
    map += ("d" -> 2);
    map += ("e" -> 4);
    map += ("f" -> 2);
    map += ("g" -> 1);

    limitMapper(map)
  }

  def limitMapper(map: Map[String, Long]): Unit = {
    var offset = 0L;

    var result = Vector[Vector[String]]()
    var list = Vector[String]()
    val iterator: Iterator[(String, Long)] = map.toVector.iterator
    val LIMIT: Int = 10
    while (iterator.hasNext) {
      val (path, size) = iterator.next()
      println((path, size))

      offset += size
      if (offset > LIMIT) {
        offset = size;
        result = result :+ list
        list = Vector[String]()
      }

      list = list :+ path
    }

    //add remaining paths
    if (list.size > 0) {
      result = result :+ list
      list = Vector[String]()
    }

    println(result)
    println(s"LIMIT = $LIMIT")


  }
}


Output:
(e,4)
(f,2)
(a,5)
(b,5)
(g,1)
(c,3)
(d,2)
Vector(Vector(e, f), Vector(a, b), Vector(g, c, d))
```

Comment: Use `grouped` on your `map`.

Comment: I tried it, but it won't be accurate because some sizes might be too small. map.groupBy(map.sum / limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
val (_, lastList, otherLists) = map.foldLeft(0L, List[String](), List[List[String]]()) {
  case ((soFar, newList, oldLists), (path, size)) =>
    if (soFar + size > limit)
      (size, List(path), newList :: oldLists)
    else
      (soFar + size, path :: newList, oldLists)
}
lastList :: otherLists
```

Comment: cool! it works. great. how does :: work? how is it different from :+ append and +: prepend.

Comment: If the first element processed has a ``size`` greater than ``limit`` then you will prepend ``Nil`` to ``oldLists``.

Comment: @wmmeyer True, I had realized that and decided to ignore the issue. It's not really clear if we should return that element in a group by itself or throw an exception because we can't guarantee that groups are smaller than limit.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner The libraries I have seen for dealing with this kind of problem ([Data.BinPack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Binpack-0.4.1/docs/Data-BinPack.html)) will group as many elements as possible and return the elements they were unable to pack. But given that we are going to include elements greater than the limit we could at least not include an extraneous ``Nil`` :)

Comment: @wmmeyer Of course, a third possibility :) I'll leave it as is because I really only mean for this to be an example. Anyone putting something like this into production does need to decide what it should do with too big elements.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it is the nicest approach. But I'd do something like:

```
val map = ...
val limit = 1073741824L

val res = map.foldLeft(Vector(Vector[String]())){ case (result, (path, size)) => 
  if(result.last.map(map(_)).sum + size > limit) {
    result :+ Vector(path)
  } else result.updated(result.size - 1, result.last :+ path)
}
```